# What purpose did the IMAP4.Literal attribute serve and how was it used?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I am handling connections to an IMAP server using the Python standard imaplib library.

I create an IMAP4 object like this:

```
import imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com') # Open imaplib connection
```

The resulting object has these methods and attributes:

```
>>> dir(M)
['Literal',
 'PROTOCOL_VERSION',
 'Untagged_status',
 '_CRAM_MD5_AUTH',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__enter__',
 '__eq__',
 '__exit__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_append_untagged',
 '_check_bye',
 '_cmd_log',
 '_cmd_log_idx',
 '_cmd_log_len',
 '_command',
 '_command_complete',
 '_connect',
 '_create_socket',
 '_dump_ur',
 '_encoding',
 '_get_capabilities',
 '_get_line',
 '_get_response',
 '_get_tagged_response',
 '_log',
 '_match',
 '_mesg',
 '_mode_ascii',
 '_mode_utf8',
 '_new_tag',
 '_quote',
 '_simple_command',
 '_tls_established',
 '_untagged_response',
 'abort',
 'append',
 'authenticate',
 'capabilities',
 'capability',
 'certfile',
 'check',
 'close',
 'continuation_response',
 'copy',
 'create',
 'debug',
 'delete',
 'deleteacl',
 'enable',
 'error',
 'expunge',
 'fetch',
 'file',
 'getacl',
 'getannotation',
 'getquota',
 'getquotaroot',
 'host',
 'is_readonly',
 'keyfile',
 'list',
 'literal',
 'login',
 'login_cram_md5',
 'logout',
 'lsub',
 'mo',
 'myrights',
 'namespace',
 'noop',
 'open',
 'partial',
 'port',
 'print_log',
 'proxyauth',
 'read',
 'readline',
 'readonly',
 'recent',
 'rename',
 'response',
 'search',
 'select',
 'send',
 'setacl',
 'setannotation',
 'setquota',
 'shutdown',
 'sock',
 'socket',
 'sort',
 'ssl_context',
 'starttls',
 'state',
 'status',
 'store',
 'subscribe',
 'tagged_commands',
 'tagnum',
 'tagpre',
 'tagre',
 'thread',
 'uid',
 'unselect',
 'unsubscribe',
 'untagged_responses',
 'utf8_enabled',
 'welcome',
 'xatom']
```

By default, the Literal attribute contains a re (regular expression) object:

```
>>> type(M.Literal)
re.Pattern
>>> print(M.Literal)
re.compile(b'.*{(?P<size>\\d+)}$', re.ASCII)
```

In the source code for imaplib.py, the attribute is defined on lines 113-114:

```
# Literal is no longer used; kept for backward compatibility.
Literal = re.compile(br'.*{(?P<size>\d+)}$', re.ASCII)
```

What was it used for and how, and what, if anything, replaced it?

Comment: It seems like the quickest way to answer that question is to look at older versions of Python. Check out the repository, see when that comment was added, and then look at older versions of the code.

Answer (score 1):

That comment was added in commit a6429db4b837dc49eb1bee42617798aebd7b43d4, which defined a similar constant `_Literal` that was used to define an instance attribute named `Literal` that is now used in place of the original global `Literal`.

So the *pattern* is still used, just not via a module global.

Before:

```
$ git checkout a6429db4b837dc49eb1bee42617798aebd7b43d4\^
$ grep Literal Lib/imaplib.py
Literal = re.compile(br'.*{(?P<size>\d+)}$', re.ASCII)
            while self._match(Literal, dat):
```

After:

```
$ git checkout a6429db4b837dc49eb1bee42617798aebd7b43d4
$ grep Literal Lib/imaplib.py
# Literal is no longer used; kept for backward compatibility.
Literal = re.compile(br'.*{(?P<size>\d+)}$', re.ASCII)
_Literal = br'.*{(?P<size>\d+)}$'
        self.Literal = re.compile(_Literal, re.ASCII)
        self.Literal = re.compile(_Literal)
            while self._match(self.Literal, dat):
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what purpose does it serve? I can't see what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: It's matching an integer literal. Is your question about the code, or the IMAP protocol?